# Bootstrap span is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying the Bootstrap and I have the following html, there is no error on the Chrome console but the bootstrap span does not work. Am I missing something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <style type="text/css" src="css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>
    <style type="text/css" src="css/app.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>Column one</h2>
            <p>
                Something
            </p>
        </div>  
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>Column one</h2>
            <p>
               Something else
            </p>
        </div>  
        <div class="span4">
            <h2>Column one</h2>
            <p>
               Something different
            </p>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Controllers/EventController.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? V3 doesn't use `spanX` anymore, it uses `col-md-X` / `col-sm-X` / `col-xs-X` etc.

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh instead of having 3 columns in horizontal order, the colums are one above the other.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder propably that is the problem, I am using v3.1.1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But how would he choose which to use ? his site can run on many devices. using spanX , you could tell the division by 12 parts. and now - how would he divide it ? (md / sm / xs ) ? the whole point is  that the css should use the division automatically. what am i missing?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you mean, how to choose which size column to use, that's a complex topic best left to the Bootstrap documentation to describe. :-) You still get the 12 columns, but the classes you use determine things like the minimum width of those columns. The docs also talk about mixing them, which I frankly haven't got my head round yet.

Comment: @Avraam Please validate your code http://validator.w3.org/  , I think  there is a problem html doctype

Comment: what verison of bootstrap are you using , is it bootstrap 2 or bootstrap 3

Comment: @ShibinRagh: The doctype is valid.

Comment: call css from cdn (for checking)  //netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: @ShibinRagh you were right, the document was not valid. thank you.

Comment: @Avraam What was the real problem ? bootstrap version missing ?

Comment: @ShibinRagh yes the problem was that I am using the latest version and `span` is not used anymore

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've said you're using v3.1.1. The problem is that v3 doesn't use `spanX` anymore, it uses `col-md-X` / `col-sm-X` / `col-xs-X` etc. More in [the v3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and [the migration guide](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/).

So if you change your `span4` class to (say) `col-md-4`, you should get the spanning.

Note that the cells will still stack if the viewport is too small; that's what the various different column classes are for. For instance, look at this with your browser at various widths ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/qoyogevi/1)):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll see that as you make your viewport narrower, the large ones stack first; then if you keep going the mediums stack; then the smalls, etc.

Comment: I did that change but still not working, it seems that there is another problem now. I edited my post.

Comment: @Avraam: They'll stack if the viewport is too narrow. If `col-md-X` didn't work for you, you might consider `col-sm-X` or `col-xs-X`.